The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated
Here my problem, i was trying to launch a basic code from Android app Studio but unfortunatly, this error appeared : The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated.
I tried many solution as untick/ tick the case Android Emulator from SDK Manager or looked for the VULKAN-1.DLL located from this repertory C:\Users<votre-utilisateur>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log. But no one was working. If somebody has an answer, feel free to respond on the chat.
